# Return original search terms for grep in R

Tags: r, regex, search

I have a list of items and a list of search terms, and I am trying to do two things:

1. Search through the items for matches to any of the search terms, and return true 
   iff a match is found.
2. For all items where true is returned (i.e., there was a match), I would like to
      also return the original search term which was matched in step 1.

So, given the following data frame:

```
             items
1             alex
2 alex is a person
3   this is a test
4            false
5    this is cathy
```

and the following list of search terms:

```
"alex"      "bob"       "cathy"     "derrick"   "erica"     "ferdinand"
```

I would like to create the following output:

```
             items matches original
1             alex    TRUE     alex
2 alex is a person    TRUE     alex
3   this is a test   FALSE     <NA>
4            false   FALSE     <NA>
5    this is cathy    TRUE     cathy
```

Step 1 is fairly straightforward, but I am having trouble with step (2).  To create the 'matches' column, I use `grepl()` to create a variable which is `TRUE` if a row in `d$items` is in the list of search terms, and `FALSE` otherwise.

For step 2, my thought was that I should be able to just use `grep()` while specifying `value = T`, as shown in my code below.  However, this returns the wrong value: rather than return the original search term which was matched by grep, it returns the value of the item that was matched.  So I get the following output:

```
            items matches original
1             alex    TRUE     alex
2 alex is a person    TRUE     alex is a person
3   this is a test   FALSE     <NA>
4            false   FALSE     <NA>
5    this is cathy    TRUE     this is cathy
```

This is the code I am using right now.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

```
# Dummy data and search terms
d = data.frame(items = c("alex", "alex is a person", "this is a test", "false", "this is cathy"))
searchTerms = c("alex", "bob", "cathy", "derrick", "erica", "ferdinand")

# Return true iff search term is found in items column, not between letters
d$matches = grepl(paste("(^| |[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ])", 
    searchTerms, "($| |[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ])", sep = "", 
    collapse = "|"), d[,1], ignore.case = TRUE
)

# Subset data
dMatched = d[d$matches==T,]   

# This is where the problem is: return the value that was originally matched with grepl above
dMatched$original = grep(paste("(^| |[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ])", 
    searchTerms, "($| |[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ])", sep = "", 
    collapse = "|"), dMatched[,1], ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE
)


d$original[d$matches==T] = dMatched$original
```

Comment: You can replace the long strings of letters with `[:alpha:]`.

Comment: You might want to check out the `regmatches` function.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the tip.  [:alpha:] and other predefined character classes never seem to work for me, though.  It must have something to do with my locale.  From the regular expression documentation on character classes:  "(Because their interpretation is locale- and implementation-dependent, they are best avoided.) The only portable way to specify all ASCII letters is to list them all as the character class
[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]."

Comment: @SteveS Yea, usually works for me, so I didn't know how accurate that warning was in general.

Comment: The syntax is `grep("[[:alpha:]]", c("123", "one"))` or for negation `"[^[:alpha:]]"`; if encoding of the file was important, then probably you wouldn't be satisfied with looking for ASCII letters, so the "portable" commentary is probably not relevant in the way you've interpreted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfectly what you want but you can use `qdap`'s `termco` function to do this.  This will help in case you have two names in the same sentence:

```
library(qdap)
termco(d$items, 1:nrow(d), searchTerms)

## > termco(d$items, 1:nrow(d), searchTerms)
##   nrow(d word.count       alex bob     cathy derrick erica ferdinand
## 1      1          1 1(100.00%)   0         0       0     0         0
## 2      2          4  1(25.00%)   0         0       0     0         0
## 3      3          4          0   0         0       0     0         0
## 4      4          1          0   0         0       0     0         0
## 5      5          3          0   0 1(33.33%)       0     0         0
```

To get what you're after with qdap you can use:

```
dat <- termco(d$items, 1:nrow(d), searchTerms)$raw
terms <- character()

for (i in 3:ncol(dat)){
    terms <- paste(terms, ifelse(dat[, i] == 1, colnames(dat)[i], ""))
}

d$matches <- as.logical(rowSums(dat[, -c(1:2)]))
x <- gsub(" ", ", ", clean(trim(terms)))
d$original <- replacer(x, "", NA)

## > d
##              items matches original
## 1             alex    TRUE     alex
## 2 alex is a person    TRUE     alex
## 3   this is a test   FALSE     <NA>
## 4            false   FALSE     <NA>
## 5    this is cathy    TRUE    cathy
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution as well.  I think I like it better, since it also tells you whether multiple search terms match the items list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Dason for the helpful tip!  I was able to solve my problem by using `regmatches()`.  Here is my code, starting from where the original problem was:

```
# This is where the problem is: return the value that was originally matched with grepl above
m = regexpr(paste("(^| |[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ])", 
    searchTerms, "($| |[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ])", sep = "", 
    collapse = "|"), dMatched[,1], ignore.case = TRUE 
)

dMatched$original = regmatches(dMatched[,1], m)

d$original[d$matches==T] = dMatched$original
```

This returns the following output, which is exactly what I want:

```
             items matches original
1             alex    TRUE     alex
2 alex is a person    TRUE    alex 
3   this is a test   FALSE     <NA>
4            false   FALSE     <NA>
5    this is cathy    TRUE    cathy
```